# Detecting a System On a Chip (SOC) platform under Windows with C++

Tags: c++, windows

What is the best way to detect programmatically (using C++ in Windows) that the hardware has CPU and GPU placed nearby (on the same chip)?

Comment: Why?   I can't imagine how you would change software behavior based on this knowledge.

Comment: I hoped to leave the reason behind the scenes in an attempt to evade obvious answers. Anyway, the application would like to know that GPU can quickly access CPU memory in order to select an appropriate computing algorithm.

Comment: Then you don't want to know if you have SOC.  You want to know if you have high bandwidth/low latency between the CPU/GPU.  You should be able to measure the speed between them programatically.

Comment: @abelenky: I anticipated your proposal :). Still, I would like to know if it is easy to detect a SoC platform (e.g. by using CPUID flags).

Comment: Sounds like you mean APU, not SoC.  There's a lot more to an SoC than just CPU + GPU.

Comment: Win-x86 or also the newfangled ARM thingies? The latter will almost certain be SoCs. (True SoCs, even.) And while they do have a `CPUID`, it means something entirely different.

Comment: @MSaltes. ARM support would be a nice compliment to the detection method. I guess we'll see more and more of those on consumer PC's.

Comment: @BenVoigt. Detecting APU can be seen as a sub-task.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `GetNativeSystemInfo` [(link)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724340%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API function to get some information about the main processor. It doesn't tell if it's an SOC, but it could be a starting point. I think it tells when it's definitely **not** an SOC, but I have not tried it on other platforms than ordinary PCs / Laptops.

```
void WINAPI GetNativeSystemInfo(
  _Out_  LPSYSTEM_INFO lpSystemInfo
);
```

It returns a `SYSTEM_INFO` structure [(link)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724958%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
typedef struct _SYSTEM_INFO {
  union {
    DWORD  dwOemId;
    struct {
      WORD wProcessorArchitecture;
      WORD wReserved;
    };
  };
  DWORD     dwPageSize;
  LPVOID    lpMinimumApplicationAddress;
  LPVOID    lpMaximumApplicationAddress;
  DWORD_PTR dwActiveProcessorMask;
  DWORD     dwNumberOfProcessors;
  DWORD     dwProcessorType;
  DWORD     dwAllocationGranularity;
  WORD      wProcessorLevel;
  WORD      wProcessorRevision;
} SYSTEM_INFO;
```

This structure contains the following information in the member `dwProcessorType`:

```
PROCESSOR_INTEL_386 (386)
PROCESSOR_INTEL_486 (486)
PROCESSOR_INTEL_PENTIUM (586)
PROCESSOR_INTEL_IA64 (2200)
PROCESSOR_AMD_X8664 (8664)
PROCESSOR_ARM (Reserved)
```

the member `wProcessorLevel` shows the vendor-defined processor level, and `wProcessorRevision` shows the vendor-defined revision number of the processor.

*This answer is mainly a copy of another of my answers.*